# Does machine learning implies that it wont have to check with any database?

Tags: face-recognition

I am doing a face recognition project on face recognition based on neural network.It includes training the system on various images.Does that mean that after training the system on various images it recognize people without matching it from any database?Like in character reading if we train our system with all the character can it recognize a new character without any further training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face recognition involves a situation where you want to give the system an image (a newly observed face) and have it compare to a set of previously defined images.

The training will consist of developing a neural network that does a better and better job of doing this job (i.e. matching a new image to a stored image).  However, even after training, you still need that set of stored images.

If you're only interested in one face (e.g. you want a system that can learn to recognize you, but no one else), then I suppose you could train a neural network to recognize that image, and then the image properties would be "built in" to the trained neural network.  But that seems both less useful and less efficient than training the system to match against a database, and then providing that database.

Or do you mean that you want the system to see a person, and then later "know" that person if they see them again?  If so, again, the efficient way would be to train the system to reduce a face to a set of characteristics, and store them in a database for later matching.

Comment: what does training on the known databases impart to the face recognition system?

Comment: You're not training on the known databases.  You could train on a smiley face if you like.  The training is meant to teach the system to compare one image to another.  Then, in the real world, the one image is presented (e.g. from a camera), but where does the other image come from?  From a database.

Comment: i want to ask what does those database like yale database or feret database impart to a face recognition system?

Comment: Ah; the question is very unclear.  These databases (Feret, Yale) are used for training and testing facial recognition; they include a variety of sample people including pictures taken from a variety of angles and with a variety of expressions.  You would not expect those databases to be used once the system is trained (other than for testing).  But presumably the goal is, instead, to have the system work against a database such as images of known terrorists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of using a neural network in any system is to impart decision making to the system.  If we want our system to make any decision it must have some rules to follow.  Training the neural network imparts the system with the knowledge and ability to make the decision.  If we have a set of 10 images for each subject we may use 6-7 images for training and the rest for testing purpose.
Training of a neural network is of 2 types: supervised and unsupervised.  Unsupervised learning is based upon some past knowledge, the system can make a decision based on a new type of data.  It really doesn't need to check any database after it has been trained.  But in supervised learning, the class of the data is known and it will recognize them only.